# List modules in shell like in erlang

Tags: shell, module, erlang, erlang-shell

I have code in erlang for listing module path for a module:

```
code:get_object_code(Module)
```

Do we have anything similar in shell?

I know we can list modules in shell by :

```
module list
```

But it specifically does not give the module path for particular module name

I have tried with:

```
module show module_name
output: ModuleCmd_Display.c(151):ERROR:105: Unable to locate a modulefile for 'module_name'
```

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with `bash`, as `module` appears to be a command you could run from *any* shell.

Comment: Yes, I did not know how to frame it in question.I have edited the question now. So can you suggest me ways on how i can do it?

Comment: @KajalPanigrahi Is this the tool you're using? http://modules.sourceforge.net/

Comment: yes, I use from modules.sourceforge.net @legoscia

Comment: I posted an answer. Let me know if I understood your question correctly :)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work if you give the name as returned by `module list`. For example, I have two active modules:

```
$ module list
Currently Loaded Modulefiles:
 1) module-info   2) module-git
```

I can ask for information about, say, `module-git`, and the output contains the file name of the module, including directory:

```
$ module show module-git
-------------------------------------------------------------------
/home/magnus/modules/modulefiles/module-git:

module-whatis   {get last version of the module sources from GitHub}
set-alias       get-modules {git clone git://github.com/cea-hpc/modules.git && cd modules}
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Actually this is where I am stuck. In erlang I am able to find that module but when i try with module list, I do not see it. Can it happen that the module i am finding is a submodule to a main module and maybe it is the reason of not showing in module list?

Comment: Hm, Erlang modules and the modules used by the `module` tool are different things, so you wouldn't see Erlang modules with `module list` or vice versa. What is it you're trying to do?

Comment: I wanted to find out the path that I got from erlang code, how and where it gets set (in some env variable maybe), since I am not much aware of erlang language, it is being difficult for me of find out.

Comment: You can see the list of directories in the Erlang code path with `code:get_path()`. The list of directories includes the "standard" built-in applications, directories from the `-pa` and `-pz` options passed to `erl` (e.g. start Erlang with `erl -pa /path/to/my/modules`), and directories listed in the `ERL_LIBS` environment variable. See [the `erl` documentation](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erl.html) for details. Does that make sense?

Comment: Right, you need a dot at the end of the line: `code:get_path().` (That's how the Erlang shell knows where the expression ends)

Comment: yeah got it. Thanks :)